# CSRF cookie not set using Django rest framework, with frontend, react and axios

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-csrf, csrf-token, djoser

I'm making an authentication application, using Django, Django framework, and react with axios.
I have already configured the csrf token in all ways and it continues to return the same error

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /auth/jwt/create/
[11/Jan/2024 10:05:28] "POST /auth/jwt/create/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2870
```

here is my settings.py configuration
setting.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    #'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False  
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False  
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'  
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True   

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.template.context_processors.csrf',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ),
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
   'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
}

DJOSER = {
    'USE_CSRF_COOKIE': False,
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE' : True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION' : True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION' : True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL' : True,
    'SEND_USERNAME_RETYPE' : True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE' : True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL' : 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL' : True,
    'SERIALIZERS' : {
        'user_create' : 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user' : 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete' : 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
}
```

here is my user.js file. In react I am sending my post request

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

// Configuração global do Axios para incluir o token CSRF em todas as solicitações
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "XCSRF-TOKEN";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

export const login = (email, password) => async dispatch => {

    const csrfToken = Cookies.get('csrftoken') || 'fallback_csrf_token';
    console.log('CSRF Token:', csrfToken);
    console.log('Cookies:', document.cookie);
    
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken,
        },
        withCredentials: true,
    };

    const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/jwt/create/`, body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });

        dispatch(load_user());
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Erro na solicitação de login:', err);
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_FAIL
        })
    }
};
```

I've tried everything I can to remove this error and I always get the same error, please can someone help me with some tips?